# merge multiple .csv files - R

Tags: r

Why I get the error "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default" when I run this code:

```
mydir = "E:/Data"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
data_csv = ldply(myfiles, read.csv(header = FALSE, sep = ";")
```

Furthermore as all of them as the same header How can I only read it once?

Comment: I guess you meant `data_csv = lapply(myfiles, read.csv, header = FALSE, sep = ";")`

Comment: Regarding the last question: Use the `skip` parameter, see `help("read.table")`. But I would read them with the header, e.g., `data_csv <- lapply(myfiles, read.csv,  sep = ";")` and then do `data_csv <- do.call(rbind, data_csv)`.

Comment: Thanks, This generate a list. How can I get  dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
data_csv <- do.call(rbind, lapply(myfiles, read.csv, sep = ";"))
```

Or with `purrr`'s `map_df`

```
data_csv <- purrr::map_df(myfiles, read.csv, sep = ";"))
```

If there are lot of files you can use `data.table` functions.

```
library(data.table)
data_csv <- rbindlist(lapply(myfiles, fread))
```